# iOS: How to animate 3 sequences with equal duration and repeat?

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiview

I would like to animate the change in color of a UIView.

I want it to change from Red -> Blue -> Yellow -> Red -> Blue ... and so on.
I want each sequence/transition to last 1 second. So 1 cycle should take 3 seconds.

Basically,

repeat {

1. red -> blue
2. blue -> yellow
3. yellow -> red

}

This is what the storyboard looks like:

[image]

My first idea was to use [animateKeyframes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622552-animatekeyframes).

```swift
UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: 3, delay: 0, options: [.repeat], animations: {
    UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0.0, relativeDuration: 1.0/3.0) {
        self.squareView.backgroundColor = .red
    }
    UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 1.0/3.0, relativeDuration: 1.0/3.0) {
        self.squareView.backgroundColor = .blue
    }
    UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 2.0/3.0, relativeDuration: 1.0/3.0) {
        self.squareView.backgroundColor = .yellow
    }
})
```

Notice how I added the `repeat` option. Each sequence lasts 1/3rd of 3 seconds = 1 second. I feel like my calculations are correct.

However, the problem is that the 3 sequences don't repeat continuously.

repeat {

1. red -> blue
2. blue -> yellow
3. yellow -> BLACK
4. BLACK -> red

}

The initial color of the square (set in the storyboard), black, is appearing between each cycle!

[image]

For a split second, you can see the black square.

If I change the initial color to red, then it looks like the red sequence lasts longer than other colors. So that doesn't fix the problem.

Using `UIView.animate` was my second attempt.

```swift
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: {
    self.squareView.backgroundColor = .red
}) { [weak self] _ in
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: {
        self?.squareView.backgroundColor = .blue
    }) { [weak self] _ in
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: {
            self?.squareView.backgroundColor = .yellow
        }) { [weak self] _ in
            self?.startAnimation()
        }
    }
}
```

This worked perfectly!

[image]

Smooth transition from red to blue to yellow, and back to red again.
But the code is rather ugly..

Is there a way I can use `animateKeyFrames` or another method to achieve what I want with clean code?

By the way, my original goal is much complicated than this. I simplified it to a single view, but the root problem is the same.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: in your first example with `animateKeyframes` you should add 4th keyframe that will animate back to black color

Comment: @Kirow Hi, that still makes the black color show up. I don't want the black to show up in the sequence :(

Answer (score 0):

To make your animation correct you need to make sure that your initial color is the same as your last color change.

So first animate `.black -> .red`, then setup repeat for `-> .blue -> .yellow -> .red`

```swift
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: {
    view.backgroundColor = .red
}, completion: { isComplete in
    UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: 3, delay: 0, options: [.repeat], animations: {
        UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0, relativeDuration: 1.0/3.0) {
            view.backgroundColor = .blue
        }
        UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 1.0/3.0, relativeDuration: 1.0/3.0) {
            view.backgroundColor = .yellow
        }
        
        UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 2.0/3.0, relativeDuration: 1.0/3.0) {
            view.backgroundColor = .red
        }
    })
})
```